# Удаления записи которой больше пяти минут

Tags: php

Я делаю так:

```
$date = date(Y-m-d H:i:s);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (date) values('$date') ");
```

Вопрос:

Как удалить эту запись через 5 минут?

Answer (score 1):

Я удаляю записи из таблицы oshibka которым больше 5 минут таким способом

```
mysql_query ("DELETE FROM oshibka WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) > 300");
```